# Edge detection then convert into a shape?

Tags: shapes, edge-detection

I was wondering if anyone knows of an algorithm to retrieve shapes from an edge detection filter.
I basically want process an image and find all the shapes in the image then fill them with rectangles using greedy fill. Though I have not found an algorithm that will help me create the shapes from edge detection.

Cam anyone point me in the right direction?